# How to pick a word in a text line in C

Tags: c

How to pick a word in a text line in string in C language?

Example string "My mother cooks well...." How I can edit only "cooks" in that string? Question is for an exam. How can I find lenght and how can I edit second word in text, for example?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int length(char* s) // Lenght
{
    int d = -1;
    while (s[++d]);
    return d;
}

int main() //main function
{
    char str[101], c;
    int i = 0;

    printf("Entry text:\n");
    scanf("%s", str); //Input text line
    printf("First word lenght('%s') je %d.\n", str, lenght(str));

    do 
    {
        scanf("%c", &c);
        str[i++] = c;
    } while (c != '\n');

    str[i - 1] = 0;
    printf("The rest: '%s'\n", str); //Rest lenght
    printf("The rest lenght: %d.", lenght(str));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just a *FYI*: to prevent buffer overflow with the`scanf` call, limit the amount of characters it can read: `scanf("%100s", str);`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `strtok()`

```
int i = 0;
char delim[2] = " ";
char *c = strtok(str, delim); //space is the delimiter.
// c points to the first word
while(c != NULL)
{
    printf(" %s\n",c);
    c = strtok(str, NULL) //notice this NULL
    i++;
    if(i == 2)
    {
        //edit your 2nd word
        //break if you want after this or carry on
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See **strstr**(3). I think that's all you need.